# am new to salesforce need clarification on apex triggers

Tags: trigger

Am new to salesforce have clarification on apex trigger.Can we use trigger.new & trigger.old in both before & after triggers.Please explain.

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 7):

> All triggers define implicit variables that allow developers to access run-time context. These variables are contained in the `System.Trigger` class.
>
> **`isExecuting`**
>   Returns `true` if the current context for the Apex code is a trigger, not a Visualforce page, a Web service, or an `executeanonymous()` API call.
>
> **`isInsert`**
>   Returns `true` if this trigger was fired due to an insert operation, from the Salesforce user interface, Apex, or the API.
>
> **`isUpdate`**
>   Returns `true` if this trigger was fired due to an update operation, from the Salesforce user interface, Apex, or the API.
>
> **`isDelete`**
>   Returns `true` if this trigger was fired due to a delete operation, from the Salesforce user interface, Apex, or the API.
>
> **`isBefore`**
>   Returns `true` if this trigger was fired before any record was saved.
>
> **`isAfter`**
>   Returns `true` if this trigger was fired after all records were saved.
>
> **`isUndelete`**
>   Returns `true` if this trigger was fired after a record is recovered from the Recycle Bin (that is, after an undelete operation from the Salesforce user interface, Apex, or the API.)
>
> **`new`**
>   Returns a list of the new versions of the sObject records.
>   Note that this sObject list is only available in `insert` and `update` triggers, and the records can only be modified in before triggers.
>
> **`newMap`**
>   A map of IDs to the new versions of the sObject records.
>   Note that this map is only available in `before update`, `after insert`, and `after update` triggers.
>
> **`old`**
>   Returns a list of the old versions of the sObject records.
>   Note that this sObject list is only available in `update` and `delete` triggers.
>
> **`oldMap`**
>   A map of IDs to the old versions of the sObject records.
>   Note that this map is only available in `update` and `delete` triggers.
>
> **`size`**
>   The total number of records in a trigger invocation, both old and new.

Please read care fully it will help you.